# AngularJS file upload sends stale formData

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, form-data

I use https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload for file uploads.

I have a form which, in addition to uploading a file, sends some other fields. For clarity, I send only one field in this example:

```js
$scope.save_with_upload = function(user) {
    $scope.uploader.formData = [{
        name: user.name,
    }];

    $scope.uploader.uploadAll();
}
```

Let’s say the value of the `name` input is *Test 1*.

1. When I first load the page and click *Save*, it sends the file but doesn’t send `formData` at all.
2. Then I change `name` field to *Test 2* and hit *Save*. It sends the file and `formData`, **but** the value of `name` it sends is *Test 1*.
3. Then I change `name` field to *Test 3* and hit *Save*. It sends the file and `formData`, **but** the value of `name` it sends is *Test 2*.
4. … and so on …

So it seems to always send the data that was assigned to `formData` *before* the last call to `uploadAll`.

To clarify: If I do `dir(user, $scope.uploader.formData)` just before calling `uploadAll`, it shows correct up-to-date values in both.

I’ve been struggling with it for a few hours and just can’t seem to see what’s wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Attaching form fields to the `FileItem` object — rather than to `FileUpload` — fixes it:

```
uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function(item) {
    formData = [{
        name: user.name,
    }];
    Array.prototype.push.apply(item.formData, formData);
};
```

The reason is, actually the settings on `FileItem` are used. When a file is added to the queue, settings from `FileUpload` are copied to `FileItem`. So any changes to `FileUpload` options made after a file has been added to the queue will have no effect.

Comment: where does this callback go? I tried it in the controller and it did not run. Can you just toss it in the view?

Comment: Also why cant you do `item.formData.push(formData)` ?

Comment: @bischoffingston This code needs to go in the controller. `uploader` has to be an instance of `FileUpload`. `item.formData.push(formData)` and `Array.prototype.push.apply(item.formData, formData)` are equivalent.